# Creating ERD and Relational Schema

Tags: database-schema, erd, entity-relationship

I wanna know how to make an ERD OR Relationship Scheme out of this. I've been practicing ERD's but this one is really confusing the hell out of me.

This is what I could make out of the narrative currently but not exactly sure how correct I am.
[image]

The owner/manager of SCBD, gives you the following information: SCBD conduct a number of
different tours to known microbrewery regions around Victoria. Each Daytrip has an ID, and a
description, and may run many times in a year (such as the West Daytrip). Frequency depends
on the season and the specific daytrip.. Each time it is run it is called an ‘Event’. Each event has
a fee. Fees have usually increased by around 10% each year. SCBD have a number of
customers. Each customer has a name, ID and gender. SCBD customers make bookings for
daytrip events. Payment is made by credit card. (you do not have to worry about recording
credit card details etc.). The date that a booking is made is also recorded.

Comment: You dont display or logic in ERD's. Where exactly would you want to place and or?

Comment: i meant i need to make an ERD and then also convert that to a Relational Scheme which is a separate part